# Call an Oracle Stored Function that returns a user defined type with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, hibernate

I have encountered a problem with Hibernate, Spring and Oracle the other day : how can I call a stored function that returns a user defined type (Oracle object) with Hibernate.

I started thinking I'dd build an Entity that defines the Oracle user type but the problem is I have no existing table to map only a function name. Then I tried making a basic query but I don't know how to exploit the returned object.

Here's my source code :

```
-- Main function

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "ECOMMERCE"."NOMBRECOMMANDESPERIODE" (v_dateDebut DATE, v_dateFin DATE)
    RETURN t_commandes_periode
IS
    v_nombre_commandes NUMBER;
    v_nombre_commandes_non_livrees NUMBER;
    v_nombre_commandes_impayees NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(c.id), 0)
        INTO v_nombre_commandes
    FROM Commande c
    WHERE c."date" >= v_dateDebut
        AND c."date" <= v_dateFin;

    v_nombre_commandes_non_livrees := commandesNonLivrees(v_dateDebut, v_dateFin).COUNT;
    v_nombre_commandes_impayees := commandesImpayees(v_dateDebut, v_dateFin).COUNT;

    RETURN t_commandes_periode(v_nombre_commandes, v_nombre_commandes_non_livrees, v_nombre_commandes_impayees);
END;
/

-- The returned type

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "ECOMMERCE"."T_COMMANDES_PERIODE" AS OBJECT (
  nombreTotal       NUMBER,
  nombreNonLivrees  NUMBER,
  nombreImpayees    NUMBER
);
/
```

How can I call that function with Hibernate to be able to work with a Java object that reflects the `T_COMMANDES_PERIODE` user defined type ?

I thank anyone who'll try to help me with this problem of mine :).

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I gave up on it, it was to awkward...

Comment: Thanks Vincent for your response! I am also moving away from this, going to use Stored Procedure support in JPA 2.1 [JPA 2.1 Stored Procedures](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#JPA_2.1_StoredProcedureQuery)